# struct inside class.h

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "algorithm.h"


struct PlusPoint {
    bool used;
    int id;
    int plusScore;

    PlusPoint(bool pUsed, int pId):used(pUsed), id(pId) {}
};

struct CompareToPlusPoint {
    bool    operator()(PlusPoint a1, PlusPoint a2)  { return a1.plusScore < a2.plusScore ; }
};

using namespace std;

class MainCharacter
{
private:
    vector<PlusPoint> plusPoints;
public:
    // try plus points if we can win the monster
    bool TryPlusPoint(vector<Node>::iterator node) {

            ...
        // sort plusPoint
        sort(plusPoints.begin(), plusPoints.end(), CompareToPlusPoint() );

        for( int i = 0 ; i < (int)plusPoints.size() ; ++i ) {

            vector<PlusPoint>::iterator it; // This produces error
            // PlusPoint plusPoint = plusPoints[i];
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Error :

```
error C2974: 'std::vector' : invalid template argument for '_Ty', type expected
```

More informations:

- All combines fine when I comment the line producing error above.
- Node are included through #include "Node.h", I only post part of the codes so you can look around easily. [ Included ]
- **When I define this iterator outside of this file, there is no error.**

My questions:

- How can I fix it ?
- Why ?

Comment: Where is `Node` defined?

Comment: @Nawaz: I've added more information to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact, that the code is missing some includes (`vector`,`algorithm`), there is no such thing as `Node` and `plusPoints`, it compiles just fine.

Comment: @nXqd Still compiles just fine.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : There is no error if I declare this iterator outside of this class.h

Comment: @nXqd Your `Node.h` might be broken.

Comment: ok, it looks like this. Thanks, this should be the answer. I will recheck my file :)

Comment: @nXqd btw. don't include system includes using `"file"` use `<file>`

Comment: @ok, I find the problem, I have function called PlusPoint, holy **** :)) All day coding makes me blinded :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code should compile. My suggestion is that your real code looks a bit different, and you might have done the following (or similar) mistake :

```
PlusPoint plusPoint = plusPoints[i]; 
vector<plusPoint>::iterator it; // Note: plusPoint - variable name, 
// not PlusPoint-class name)
```

At least it's how I can reproduce your error.

Comment: There is no way, I've checked it. I copy this line to outside of this class.h and it works without any errors. Errors like this piss me off everytime @.@

Comment: Don't you have something like `PlusPoint PlusPoint = plusPoints[1];` in this function? Surprisingly you can compile such code, but later you will get error when you write `vector<PlusPoint>`

Answer (score 0):

Mind reader mode activate:

If I replace ... with PlusPoint PlusPoint(true,1);

I got your error message. (Using visual studio 2010)

**EDIT**

My bad, actually a similar error

error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'PlusPoint' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

This code reproduce your error:

enum { PlusPoint }; instead of ...

error C2974: 'std::vector' : invalid template argument for '_Ty', type expected

The compiler complains because PlusPoint is not a type any more.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the statement:

```
vector<PlusPoint>::iterator it;
```

is incorrect. Iterator shall always be initialized with something.
Just common sense.

Comment: It is a very good idea to initialize the iterator, but you can also assign it a valid value later, before using it.

Comment: Yes it is. But what first is first, this should not produce any errors. I define something like this outside this class.h, there is no error.